# NativeScript/Angular - Reactive form not working when using actionbar

Tags: nativescript, angular-reactive-forms, nativescript-angular

First I implemented the code below.

**app.component.html**

```
<StackLayout [formGroup]="form">
    <label text="Name"></label>
    <TextField formControlName="Name"></TextField>   
    <label text="Last Name"></label>
    <TextField formControlName="LastName"></TextField>
    <button text="save" (tap)="save()"></button>
</StackLayout>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
public form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        "Name": ["", [Validators.required]],
        "LastName": ["", [Validators.required]]
    });
}

public save(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
}
```

When I run the code above, it's everything alright. I get name and lastname correctly.

The problem occurs when I try to add an action bar to this code.

**app.component.html**

```
<ActionBar title="New" class="action-bar">        
    <ActionItem text="save" (tap)="save()"></ActionItem>       
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout [formGroup]="form">
   <label text="Name"></label>
   <TextField formControlName="Name"></TextField>   
   <label text="Last Name"></label>
   <TextField formControlName="LastName"></TextField>
   <button text="save" (tap)="save()"></button> 
</StackLayout>
```

The **app.component.ts** remains the same.

When I run this code and tap the button inside stacklayout I get name and lastname correctly but when I tap the ActionItem I get an empty string for both name and lastname. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks just fine - in fact I have re=-tested it with [this test application](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/formBuilder) and everything works as expected on my side.

Side note: If testing on iOS keep in mind that subsequent console logs can be printed only once if they are identical. ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090288/how-to-disable-ios-console-filtering-out-same-messages)) so it might be that it appears that the log is not printed when in fact the action is done.

Comment: Thanks Nick :) now it's working. My code was in AppComponent so I created another component, pasted my code there and it's fine. Can the page router outlet in app.component.html be the reason why my code did not work before?