# How to disable iOS console filtering out same messages?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I'm doing NativeScript work, using the iOS console.

When I debug, I usually `console.log(something)`.

However, subsequent triggers of the same event will be blocked on the console.

According to https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3

> The iOS
>   console will filter out similar messages and will show them only once.
>   That is why when you keep on clicking the button, you will see hello
>   only printed on the console once. Replace the string "hello" with the
>   following back-tick string hello ${new Date()} to verify that the tap
>   event does work. Printing the current time will make sure the string
>   is different every time and the console will have to show it.

Is there a way to disable this "feature" of iOS console?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this case, you can also print two lines of `console.log` instead one.

e.g.

```
console.log(something);
console.log("...");
```

And now even if the logs are identical it will print them each time even on subsequent triggers.

Comment: So literally a line that's like console.log('ignore me'). Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Nick's workaround, you could force the console logs not to be the same:

```
console.log(Date.now(), "My duplicate thing");
console.log(Date.now(), "My duplicate thing");
```